# consulta anidada en codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sql

soy nuevo con codeigniter, necesito realizar la impresión de datos en una vista, pero esos datos dependen de una consulta previa (consulta anidada). Algo así como:
idhorario, materia, docente, lunes, martes, miercoles, jueves, viernes

los tres primeros atributos son de la consulta general por defecto, pero el horario por dia de la semana es lo que deseo conseguir (otra consulta), alguien me podría orientar???

Les dejo un pedazo de código de la forma tradicional en que lo he resuelto alteriormente.

```
$horario="select g.idg, h.idh, h.idmat, p.sem, h.idoc, h.cupo,  p.idcar, d.nomdoc, m.nommat from encarre as e, hgrupo as g, horario as h, posee as p, docente as d, materias as m where e.idg=g.idg and e.idcar=p.idcar and g.idh=h.idh and p.idmat=m.idmat and h.idmat=m.idmat and d.idoc=h.idoc and p.idmat=h.idmat and p.idcar='$c->idcar' and h.periodo='$periodo' order by g.idg, p.sem;";

$hora=mysql_query($horario,$conexion);
while($h=mysql_fetch_object($hora))
{
    $lunes="select * from imparte as i, reloj as r, aula as a where a.ida=i.ida and r.idr=i.idr and i.idh='$h->idh' and i.idia='1';";
    $lu=mysql_query($lunes,$conexion);
    $rlu=mysql_num_rows($lu);
    //son distintas horas en que se imparte por dia, se crea el while para realizar la impresion de la consulta
    if($rlu>0)
    {
        while($l=mysql_fetch_object($lu))
        {echo"$l->hora / $l->aula <br>";}
    }
    //Martes, miercoles, etc
}
```

muchas gracias por las sugerencias que me puedan realizar, o hay alguna manera de hacerlo directamente desde la vista!??!?!

Answer (score 0):

para versiones menores a la 4

```
$query = $this->db->query('tu consulta sql');
```

si ya estas usando la version 4

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$query = $db->query('tu consulta sql');
```

hacerlo desde la vista no es una buena idea incluso va en contra del patron MVC el cual pone en práctica Codeigniter. Lo ideal es tomar los datos del modelo desde metodo del controlador,  y despues llamar a la vista pasandole esos datos.

Comment: Gracias, el detalle es que de la primera consulta requiero el idh para hacer la siguiente consulta, la primera me sale bien, pero no sé cómo incluir idh para la segunda. Gracias amigo

Comment: es que no estas concatenando correctamente  en la segunda consulta el idh de la primera consulta.          ....and i.idh='$h->idh'..... deberias cambiarlo a and i.idh=".$h->idh.".